# Call a server utilities in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my Nuxt3 app, I am trying to ask the server to send an email.

I know how to call an api through server/api but I can't deal with server utilities.

My server utility is defined as follows, in /server/utils/mail/send.ts:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(() => 'You try to send an email !');
```

I try to call it in a component as follow:

```js
console.log(await useFetch('/utils/mail/send'));
```

But the route seems to not be known from the server, I get the error: 'GET http://localhost:3000/utils/mail/send 404 (Page not found: /utils/mail/send)' in the browser console, and this one in the server console: '[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/utils/mail/send"'

Can someone explain to me how to use server utilities ? The nuxt documentation redirect to [unjs/h3](https://github.com/unjs/h3) documentation but it is not very clear.

Comment: Put your file in `~/server/api/...` and call `/api/...`. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server/

Comment: Yeah I know how does it work, but I want to know how does it work with a server utility because for me API is here to communicate with a database

Comment: Your definition of API seems a bit uncommon.

Comment: Can you tell me which verb is the most apropriated to send an email through an API ?

Comment: `POST` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762376/right-http-verb-for-sending-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sendMail from '~/server/utils/mail/send’

console.log(await sendMail());
```

You can see more [here](https://medium.com/@shahriarrahi/create-api-with-nuxt3-adcb7b6a17dd)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34671273)